# How to assign values to image in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have 5 columns x, y, r, g, b with values of line number, column number, red, green and blue. The lines of this n by 5 matrix are not in a particular order, however they are consistent with image(x,y) and the r,g,b.

I would like to do something like `I=uint8(zeros(480,640,3)` and just change those rgb values based on the n by 5 mat.

Something along the lines of `I(mat(:,1), mat(:,2), 1)=mat(:,3) for red etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses the concept of [linear indexing](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) and the versatile [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) function:

```
m = 640; %// number of rows
n = 480; %// number of columns
I = zeros(m, n, 3, 'uint8'); %// initiallize directly as uint8
I(bsxfun(@plus, x(:)+(y(:)-1)*m, (0:2)*m*n)) = [r(:) g(:) b(:)]; %// fill values
```

Small example: for

```
m = 2;
n = 3;
x = [1 2 1];
y = [1 1 2];
r = [ 1  2  3];
g = [11 12 13];
b = [21 22 23];
```

the code produces

```
I(:,:,1) =
    1    3    0
    2    0    0

I(:,:,2) =
   11   13    0
   12    0    0

I(:,:,3) =
   21   23    0
   22    0    0
```

Comment: this seems to work, but appears to be shifting pixels slightly to the left and upwards than their expected position

Comment: Hmm... not in my example above. Are you using 0-based indexing, maybe?

Comment: it looks like that ... I have a mex that generates those values in c++

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, I simply added 1 to all x and y and now the pixels are where they belong

Comment: @valentin Yes, Matlab uses 1-based indexing, not 0-based indexing as C++ and other languages do. That may be confusing. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
INDr = sub2ind([480, 640, 3], mat(:, 1), mat(:,2), ones([numel(mat(:,3)), 1]));
INDg = sub2ind([480, 640, 3], mat(:, 1), mat(:,2), 2*ones([numel(mat(:,3)), 1]));
INDb = sub2ind([480, 640, 3], mat(:, 1), mat(:,2), 3*ones([numel(mat(:,3)), 1]));

I=uint8(zeros(480,640, 3));

I(INDr)=mat(:,3);
I(INDg)=mat(:,4);
I(INDb)=mat(:,5);
```

**Note** that in Matlab, the convention between axes is different between images and arrays.